# How can I change my C++ code to use as a DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am learning how to call methods in C++ from C#. I have done some research and it seems Pinvoke is a nice way.

How can I translate this simple C++ code to the way how it should be in order to be called in C#, and how can I write the methods to be called in C#?

I have a header file:

MathFuncsLib.h

```
namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
         public:            
       double Add(double a, double b);
       MyMathFuncs getClass();
    };
}
```

MathFuncsLib.cpp

```
#include "MathFuncsLib.h"
namespace MathFuncs
{
   MyMathFuncs MyMathFuncs::getClass() {
       return *(new MyMathFuncs());
   }

   double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b) {
       return a + b;
   }
}
```

In C#,

I would like to have:

```
main()
{
    MyMathFuncs abd = MyMathFuncs::getClass();
    abd.Add(1.2, 2.3);
}
```

I have no clue how it should be achieved, so I think it is better to ask about it.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure it can be achieved (name mangling would be one difficulty to overcome, as well as the basic premise of exporting a class), and I don't know how something like this would be done, but you might try thinking in terms of a combination of P/Invoke and C++/CLR. The blog post [If the shell is written in C++, why not just export its base classes?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/10/24/10229097.aspx) by Raymond Chen over at The Old New Thing might also be of interest to you.

Comment: Pinvoke is not what you want to call classes. To do that you are best using C++/CLI.

Comment: whatever way it is, could you two provide some a sample?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, C++/CLI was what I was thinking of, thanks for that one.

Comment: I realize the posted code is just an example, but you're heading for a bruisin'.  It can't even be safely used from a C++ program, you'll have very little luck making it work from C#.  Returning an object by value requires a copy constructor and an assignment operator overload.  There's a nasty memory management problem, the client code needs to use the proper allocator to destroy the object.  The Add() method is an instance method for no good reason.  Focus on writing good C++ code first and the interop will be a heckofalot easier.

Comment: Put in another vote for C++/CLR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

P/Invoke is more suited when you have a lot of static functions. You could instead use [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI), which is more appropriate when you have a set of C++ classes, or a structured domain model hierarchy of classes. This is how you could do it with your sample:

The .H:

```
namespace MathFuncs {

    public ref class MyMathFuncs
    {
        public:            
            double Add(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

The .CPP:

```
namespace MathFuncs
{
   double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b) {
       return a + b;
   }
}
```

The .CS:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyMathFuncs abd = new MyMathFuncs();
        abd.Add(1.2, 2.3);
    }
}
```

As you see, you don't need the getClass function as with C++/CLI, your MathFuncs class becomes a full-blown .NET class.

EDIT: if you want the actual computation (a+b in the sample) to happen in unmanaged code, you could do it like this; for example:

The .H:

```
namespace MathFuncs {

    public ref class MyMathFuncs
    {
        public:            
            double Add(double a, double b);
    };

    class MyMathFuncsImpl
    {
        public:            
            double Add(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

The .CPP:

```
namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b) {
        MyMathFuncsImpl *p = new MyMathFuncsImpl();
        double sum = p->Add(a, b);
        delete p;
        return sum;
    }

#pragma managed(push, off)
    double MyMathFuncsImpl::Add(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
#pragma managed(pop)
}
```

In this case, MyMathFuncsImpl::Add is generated as native code, not as IL (calling from C# is the same). See here: [managed, unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe.aspx) for more on how to mix managed and unmanaged code.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the math there will end up in IL, if I'm not mistaken, so if you're using C++ for the sake of math optimization, you'll have to outsource it from the class.  I know that's not the issue here, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Wow, very cool.  I had no idea you had that much control over what was managed and unmanaged--at least, not quite in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the get class, unless yor constructor is private.
If it public, use it like:

```
main()
{
    MyMathFuncs abd = new MyMathFuncs();
    abd.Add(1.2,2.3);
}
```

If you want your constructor to be private and use the getClass to get an instance of your class, you should make that method static like:

```
namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
       public double Add(double a, double b);
       static MyMathFuncs getClass() { return new MyMathFuncs(); }
    };
}
```

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the pinvoke and interop issues. Quite how do you expect to call a C++ function from C# code?

Comment: @Seffix: I would like to make it: MyMathFuncs abd = MyMathFuncs::getClass(); in order to understand how an object from C++ is retrieved in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper class around your defined class in c++/cli or managed c++.It is like a layer which can cummunicate directly with both native c++ and c#

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Visual Studio (Express), I created the class as per normal (without the `main()` function of course) but you may choose to compile as `.dll`. The advantage is that, the class will be in a separate file which can be reused/called from other applications that you are developing.